# Spring and Thymeleaf Fragments

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am developing a Spring Boot application and using Thymeleaf Templating.  I am new to this and need a little guidance.  I have a index.html file which is the main view which should be displayed.  Inside the index.html file i have two fragments, a header and a footer which display as well.  What i am having trouble with is inserting more fragments into the index.html file.  I want to insert another fragment which displays a navigation top bar as well as a second fragment that displays a side navigation menu.  I am looking to include the topnavbar right below the header fragment and the side nav menu on the left side of screen.  How do i go about doing this?  Thank you.

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"/>

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/main.css"
                       th:href="@{css/main.css}" media="screen"/>
<title>Spring Boot | Web Application</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

<div class="row" th:include="header :: banner"></div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3"><hr /></div>
<div class="col-sm-9 text-center">col-sm-8</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12"><hr /></div>
</div>

<div class="row" th:include="footer :: copy"></div>

</div>


<!-- jQuery, Popper.js, Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You know how to include fragment as you said and as shown on your code. The problem has nothing to do with Thymeleaf itself but with HTML/CSS. You are using bootstrap. Have you checked its examples - http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/?

Comment: Thank you.  I was able to solve my problem.  It was bootstrap related.

Comment: Nice! Good luck and happy coding.